# systemd start a service when another is killed/dead

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a way to start another service (or run a script) when my service
enters `inactive (dead)` state ?

For e.g., in `upstart`, I had

```
 start on stopped <otherjob>
```

In `systemd`, I see on `OnFailure=` - which is for cases when the service *fails to start*.
In my case, the daemon in running, but then gets killed (due to a signal, say), how can
I invoke another service (*trigger start of another systemd service unit* or a script)? .

Note: my service has `Restart=no`, if I check in a script invoked from `ExecStopPost=`
then I cannot distinguish between `SIGTERM` sent by user or other process vs `SIGTERM` sent
by `systemd`. I would rather want `systemd` to do the script/service invocation when my
service dies (goes *inactive/dead*)

Comment: It's not the cleanest solution, but you could create a separate timer unit and a script that checks your service periodically. If it detects it being down, the script should execute the other service.

Comment: Do you actually need to start some other service? Maybe you actually just need to do some one-off stuff before restarting the original service. Can you give some more context on how these services are meant to interact?

Comment: This is confusing. If you _always_ want another service when your first service finishes (inactive/dead is finished)  add `Wants=` and `Before=` to your first service and refer your second service. Otherwhise use `OnFailure=`. Note that there is `$EXIT_STATUS` and `$EXIT_CODE` on `ExecStopPost=` with systemd version >= v232 (you can hack a handler for this)

Comment: @EarthMind I didn't think of that, maybe that's an option too. But how would I stop this timer unit? (Can it be part of my main unit so that when that stops, the timer will stop too?)

Comment: @Michael, you're correct - I have some actions to perform before restarting the unit under question and the suite of services it belongs to. For e.g I have my set of services, say A, of which this unit B is critical, when it's stopped/killed/crashes I need to take some actions, cleanups, checks etc. And then restart all the services of the suite A.

Comment: @Beko, tried that, doesn't help! Can't distinguish between `SIGTERM` sent by `systemd` vs some other rogue daemon/user sending `SIGTERM` to my daemon (in `ExecStopPost` handler).

Comment: The timer is not the issue on that case. Your timer should just keep on running to check if your service is up or down. Your script should be the one that only starts the other service if the first one is down. If it's up it should do nothing